# Java splitting string with pipe character

Tags: java, database

I have a text file that is in this format

```
12345 | John | Male
5678  | Alyssa | Female
```

I want to insert the text file into the database, with the end result like this

```
Column1  Column2 Column3
12345    John    Male 
5678     Alyssa  Female
```

Any advice on how to code it out? I was thinking of splitting the data with pipe character, however, I can only imagine the output as

```
12345
John
Male5678
Alyssa
Female
```

As separating with pipe doesn't separate out the 'Male' and '5678'

Many thanks for reading it

Cheers

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't write a Java program. Most modern databases can either import from a flat file or give you a table-like API on top of one and then you could just insert-select it to a "real" table.

Comment: Use `line.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")`, then iterate the resulting array to populate your SQL statement.

Comment: @Mureinik No need to involve Frank here :-)

Comment: Couldn't you split it by new lines and then by pipe to get to each row, map each row to the columns, and then be finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file line by line using `Files.lines`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\test.txt");
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)) {
        stream
            .map(line -> line.split("\\|"))
            .forEach(array -> consumeLine(array[0].trim(), array[1].trim(), array[2].trim()));
    }
}

private static void consumeLine(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
    // Operate on the line
}
```